# How can I replace a taxonomy / category text string, onclick using javascript in a .md file?

Tags: javascript, string, replace, markdown, grav

Remove / Change taxonomy on button click, assuming the GRAV user is logged in.

I have tried:

```
---
taxonomy:
    tag:
        - mountain
<code>
<script>
    function removeTg() {
    var ret = "mountain".replace('mountain','');
}
</script>
</code>
---
<button onclick="removeTg()">Remove tag</button>
```

Any idea how to make scripts execute and change .md file content / strings, in a section wrapped by?

```
---
 as non visible .md taxonomy page content.
---
```

Comment: This isn't Markdown. It looks like some form of YAML front-matter, which is common in several tools, but not itself Markdown.

Comment: Please don't add "tags" to your title. Stack Overflow has real tags, which are entirely sufficient.

Comment: @Chris You're right. Grav's pages are a combination of page properties written in Yaml (between the tripple dashes) and page content written in markdown

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run a script by clicking on a button defined inside the Markdown content of a Grav page file (.md), the following snippet will work:

```
---
taxonomy:
    tag: mountain
---
<button onclick="removeTg()">Remove tag</button>
<script>
    function removeTg() {
        alert('Script is running')
    }
</script>
```

Of course, this doesn't do much. If you want to change to content of the `.md` file on the server, the script will need to submit a request to the server. A custom Grav plugin will then catch the request and update/save the `.md` file.

A few notes:

- Why would you want to do this? This is what the Admin plugin is made for...
- Markdown is meant for defining content and should be separated from logic.
- Scripts (and styles) should be in their own files.
- Twig templates then combine the content, layout, style and logic.

Comment: Thank's for the help! I would do this for automated removal of the product if the logged in customer / user clicks on buying a last one of a kind product.

Comment: I presume you keep track of available stock somewhere.I think I would not touch the tag, but would instead add some logic in the template showing the products and hide the product if none is in stock.